# Curl to get the contents of an angular page

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, node.js, curl

I am working on an angular 2 application and we need to use Google Earth to run this app. Unfortunately, Google earth uses a much ancient version of Chrome which does not know anything about Angular 2. A mechanism is needed to run the angular 2 app on server and send the initial html response with angular already executed/bootstrapped to this browser.

I am thinking of creating a PHP server which communicates with the Google earth browser. So essentially, Google Earth will request pages from this PHP server. This PHP server will make CURL requests to fetch corresponding pages from the Angular2 application and return the HTML back to the Google Earth browser.

But, there is a catch. Curl does get the response from angular apps but does not wait for angular app to finish bootstrapping, which means before ui-view is filled by the router content, CURL renders its response which happens to be useless in this case I do not get any useful HTML back.

I used this link to check the CURL responses : http://onlinecurl.com/ 
You can pick up any angular site and use this link to see the responses it give away.

Is there a way with which curl can wait till angular bootstraps and then return the HTML? or is there any any other way to solve this problem?

I have tried angular-universal but it seems too complicated to implement and I have short time to fix this issue.

All solutions welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you try some code?

Comment: sounds to me like you should have considered the requirement to use Google Earth's browser before you chose Angular as the platform for the app? Curl will just fetch a static page. It doesn't work like a browser, it doesn't run any javascript (which Angular and similar frameworks rely on). It just fetches the initial response from the server. It isn't "waiting" for angular because Angular (and any other script) is not running, because there's no browser environment to run it in.

Comment: PHP and curl can't help. The way to solve the problem is to request the page with Phantomjs or [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare). I can't say that these solutions are less complicated than Angular Universal.

Answer (score 0):

Angular breaks the [Semantic Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web), [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) in max security mode, and any other sort of compatibility short of a rendering web browser. So I recommend avoiding Angular or if that's not an options create a faster, smaller more compatible mirror of you site that serves one html.gz file per page. Use something like [Selenium IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) because "Angular Universal" has no support for window/document/jquery/etc and [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) & [nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) use old buggy code. A 2,361.07 KB [example](https://www.ontario.ca/page/jobs-and-prosperity-fund-new-economy-stream) Angular page can be reduced to a 9.7 KB flat file. Another option is if you only want the data and you use or can find the XHR JSON file that has the body HTML and just get that. `curl -sL 'https://api.ontario.ca/api/drupal/page%2Fjobs-and-prosperity-fund-new-economy-stream?fields=body' > body.json` for the above example